# Zend Form Radio Default Checked

Tags: php, zend-framework, radio-button, zend-form

I have the next radio button group:

```
$enabled = $this->createElement('radio', 'enabled')
                ->setLabel('Enabled')
                ->setMultiOptions(array('1'=>'yes', '0'=>'no'))
                ->setValue($rank_values['enabled'])
                ->setAttrib('id', 'enabled')
                ->setAttrib('class', $action . '_enabled')
                ->setSeparator('');
```

How can I set a checked radio? Now, when I open my script, there are not selected radio. I want to select 'yes'. How?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it is much more easier :)

```
$enabled = $this->createElement('radio', 'enabled')
                ->setLabel('Enabled')
                ->setMultiOptions(array('1'=>'yes', '0'=>'no'))
                ->setValue($rank_values['enabled'])
                ->setAttrib('id', 'enabled')
                ->setAttrib('class', $action . '_enabled')
                ->setSeparator('')
                ->setValue("1");
```

Answer (score 7):

In case somebody wonders, I'm using the array notation to declare all my elements in my forms and in zend framework 2 to have a default option selected in a radio button you have to add the attribute value and make it have the key of the value_options you want to be selected by default:

```
// Inside your constructor or init method for your form //
$this->add(
        [
            'type'       => 'Radio',
            'name'       => 'some_radio',
            'options'    => [
                'value_options' => [
                    'opt1' => 'Radio option 1',
                    'opt2' => 'Radio option 2'
                ]
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'value' => 'opt1' // This set the opt 1 as selected when form is rendered
            ]
        ]
    );
```

I found some examples a little confusing because they were using numeric keys in the value options (0, 1) so when I saw 'value' => 1 it wasn't obvious for me that this was the key in the value_options array. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
->setAttrib("checked","checked")
```

So that your complete code looks like this:

```
$enabled = $this->createElement('radio', 'enabled')
            ->setLabel('Enabled')
            ->setMultiOptions(array('0'=>'no', '1'=>'yes'))
            ->setAttrib("checked","checked")
            ->setValue($rank_values['enabled'])
            ->setAttrib('id', 'enabled')
            ->setAttrib('class', $action . '_enabled')
            ->setSeparator('');
```

---

**[EDIT]** Using `setValue`:

You can alternatively use this:

```
->setValue('1')
```

This will check the option represented by value `1` which is `yes`.

Comment: yes, it works if we have only one element. I have 2 elements in radio group.

Comment: Yes. It selects last element in multioptions. It selects `no`

Comment: @Alexander, that's why I REPLACED `yes` and `no` in my complete code. See it carefully.

Comment: @shamittomar, I think doing the `setAttrib` being "checked" and "checked" is setting that attribute for all elements, so the last element will generally be defaulted to the checked answer.

Comment: Ofcause. It will be work. But I NEED a `yes` first value. Indian programming... sorry.

Comment: @Alexander, then use `->setValue('1')`. This will set the `yes` as default.

Answer (score 4):

According to the manual, you would do it this way if you were to use array notation: [link to manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#zend-form-element-multicheckbox-advanced)

```
 $this->add(
        [
            'name'       => 'someRadioMethod',
            'type'       => 'radio',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Some descriptive label',
                'value_options' => [
                    [
                        'value' => '1',
                        'label' => 'Label for 1',
                        'selected' => true,

                    ],
                    [
                        'value' => '2',
                        'label' => 'Label for 2',
                        'selected' => false,

                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you have a filter set then `->setvalue('X')` does not work.

I removed `->addFilter('StringToLower')`
and added `->setSeparator('')->setValue('N');`

Worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I have resolved it using jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $radios = $('input:radio[name=enabled]');
    if($radios.is(':checked') === false) {
        $radios.filter('[value=1]').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```